# Compile with CMAKE and invalid sh_info in symbol table

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

sorry bad english

cloned and compiled this project in Android Studio:
https://github.com/Pangu-Immortal/KeepAlivePerfect/

During compile, got the following error (using ndk 24.0.8215888):

```
KeepAlivePerfect/library/src/main/cpp/binder_libs/armeabi-v7a/libbinder.so: invalid sh_info in symbol table
```

tested both in linux and windows. Same error.

plz help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I cloned the main repository from https://github.com/Pangu-Immortal/KeepAlivePerfect/ into Android Studio. My SDK and NDK are updated. When I compiled the application, I faced the error which tells: KeepAlivePerfect/library/src/main/cpp/binder_libs/armeabi-v7a/libbinder.so: invalid sh_info in symbol table

Answer (score 0):

Finally could compile with changing **SHARED** to **STATIC** in `CMakeLists.txt`. And some more config.

Here are the changes:

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/)

add_compile_options(-fno-rtti -O3 -v)

message(@@@${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

link_directories(binder_libs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI})

aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST) # 搜索当前目录下的所有.cpp文件

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        keep_alive

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        STATIC # Changed from SHARED to STATIC

        # 提供源文件的相对路径。
        ${SRC_LIST} main.cpp art.cpp)

# More Config
set_target_properties(keep_alive PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/binder_libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libutils.so)
set_target_properties(keep_alive PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/binder_libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libc.so)
set_target_properties(keep_alive PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/binder_libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcutils.so)
set_target_properties(keep_alive PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/binder_libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libutils.so)
# The END

find_library(log-lib log)

target_link_libraries(
        keep_alive
        ${log-lib}
)
```

More information in an issue in main project:
https://github.com/Pangu-Immortal/KeepAlivePerfect/issues/8#issuecomment-1107427875

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: After change ```share``` to ```static``` SO files did not add to apk!